# deleteRowsAtIndexPaths doesn't respect animation setting

Tags: ios, uitableview

When I call

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]    
withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

it doesn't matter what constant I pass to the `withRowAnimation` parameter, the animation is always the same, the row slides up behind the row above it while fading out. I want the `UITableViewRowAnimationRight` behaviour, but I also want to know why this is malfunctioning. Even if I pass `UITableViewRowAnimationNone` as a parameter, as above, the animation still fires.

---

Here’s the method’s full code in case I’m inadvertently doing something wrong elsewhere

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {            
        // Delete file represented by row
        NSString *fileDirectoryString = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filePath = [fileDirectoryString stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.files[indexPath.row]];

        NSError *error;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];

        if (!error) {
            [tableView beginUpdates];

            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

            [tableView endUpdates];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the `beginUpdates/endUpdates` calls and pass in `UITableViewRowAnimationRight` instead of `UITableViewRowAnimationNone`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Got rid of those two calls, `None` still has no effect (animation still happens) and `Right`, `Left`, `Fade` and `Automatic` all look identical.